# linearity of $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]$

Tags: probability

Let $\alpha ,\beta \in\mathbb R$ and $X,Y$ r.v. To prove $$\mathbb E[\alpha X+\beta Y\mid \mathcal G]=\alpha \mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]+\beta \mathbb E[Y\mid \mathcal G]\ \ a.s.$$ my teacher did as follow : Since for all $G\in \mathcal G$ we have $$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\alpha X+\beta Y\mid \mathcal G]\boldsymbol 1_G]=\mathbb E[(\alpha \mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]+\beta \mathbb E[Y\mid \mathcal G])\boldsymbol 1_G],\tag{*}$$ the claim follow.

**Question :** Why does the claim follow from $(*)$ ? I think from $(*)$ we can show that for all $U$ $\mathcal G-$measurable and bounded

$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\alpha X+\beta Y\mid \mathcal G]U]=\mathbb E[(\alpha \mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]+\beta \mathbb E[Y\mid \mathcal G])U],$$
but still, I don't see how to conclude.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2096041/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1016509/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1571154/321264

Answer (score 1):

Because $Z=\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]$ is the unique $\mathcal G-$measurable r.v. s.t. $$\mathbb E[XU]=\mathbb E[ZU],$$
for all bounded $\mathcal G-$measurable r.v. $U$.